# connect two PCs: direct cable vs Router

Tags: networking, router, lan, home-networking

I have two Computers within 2 meters of each other. I need to connect both of them. Now I have two options:

1) connect both of them directly via a lan cable
2) connect both of them to a common router via lan cable.

Now I would prefer the second option to access Internet in both computer through router. But what I want to know is whether I'll be making data transfer sacrifice with this option.

My primary objective is maximum data transfer speed between two computers. I want to know how much of hit in data transfer speed will I take if I connect computers through router. I have a ADSL router and let me know what other information I need to provide about the router to answer this query.

Comment: For option one you need crossover cable BTW!

Comment: @Dude Unless they are Gb NICs, as the Gb standard includes automatic crossover at the ports. :)

Comment: Almost all NICs include automatic crossover, not just GbE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introducing a router will add a delay, but the delay my be negligible.

If the router will reduce speeds to an unacceptable level will depend on the router in question, and your needs.

You should test both configurations yourself and determine if the convenience of a router outweighs the possible speed hit it introduces between machines.

Perhaps check out these other questions/answers for some ideas on how to test that:

- [Method for testing bandwidth/speed between two set points](https://superuser.com/questions/548048/method-for-testing-bandwidth-speed-between-two-set-points)
- [How to test real network throughput between two points?](https://serverfault.com/questions/5111/how-to-test-real-network-throughput-between-two-points)

Comment: Introducing a router (in a home environment) will NOT add an extra hop. Local to local connections on a home router go via the L2 bridge, and are not routed. There is more latency, but we're talking about 0.0001 seconds. All but the worst switches will forward at line speed these days.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq true enough. I was thinking of better routers that route all ports -- I've removed that bit.

Comment: Yes, a true "router" would route, but he mentions ADSL router which implies it's just a home gateway. At which point it really just comes down to whether the "router" has gigabit ports or not. Also, we're on Superuser and not ServerFault so I tend to assume towards home equipment than real business "routers"

Comment: I am a home user and it appears that there will only be a slight latency increase. Am I correct in assuming the bandwidth will not be hampered? I need to check if my router has Gigabyte ports as the NIC are Gigabye. Also, thanks for the link.. i'll try the tests once I get the second PC in about 3 days.